# Committing changes on one branch undoes unstaged changes on another branch

Tags: git

Let's say that I am on master branch, and I have 1 file `temp.py` and 1 commit, then

1) I made a change to `temp.py`

2) checkout another branch (`feature`)(I don't add or commit the file)

3) On feature branch, I `add` `temp.py` and `commit` changes

4) checkout master again, the original change that I made to `temp.py` is undone

Here is the code that does the above steps:

```
$ git branch
* master
$ cat temp.py
print "Hello World"
$ echo "print \"Bye Bye\"" >> temp.py
$ cat temp.py
print "Hello World"
print "Bye Bye"
$ git checkout -b feature
M   temp.py
Switched to a new branch 'feature'
$ git add temp.py
$ git commit -am "added Bye Bye to temp.py"
[feature d8e363a] added Bye Bye to temp.py
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ cat temp.py
print "Hello World"
$
```

Before `add` and `commit` on feature branch, `temp.py` on master was:

```
print "Hello World"
print "Bye Bye"
```

But after `add` and `commit` on feature, the change was undone, and I ended with:

```
print "Hello World"
```

I am puzzled as to why committing changes on `feature` branch affects `master` branch, why is this happening?

I know that this example is not normal usage of git, but I feel like it underlines some aspects of git that I don't understand.

This question is related to what I am asking: [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053757/checkout-another-branch-when-there-are-uncommitted-changes-on-the-current-branch), but I was not able find answer to my question there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks correct to me.  Here's where you may be confused.

When you checked out a new branch, Git *preserved* your working index and brought it along with you to the new branch.  You can see this from this line:

```
M   temp.py
```

Right now, that copy of `temp.py` is the *only* one Git is aware of with the two lines.

When you committed this change, `feature` now contains the Python file with the two lines in it.  Now you've changed back to `master` and, as expected, `master` only contains *one* line.

**You didn't commit your changes to master, so master has no working knowledge of these changes.** They exist on your feature branch instead.